# Use a cookie on subdomains defined from a sub subdomain

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, cross-domain, subdomain, session-cookies

I am trying to make an authentication page that will return a JWT usable on different subdomains through cookies. Here is the scenario I try to achieve :

1. The user goes to `authenticate.staging.example.com`
2. The page will make an HTTP request (withCredentials: true) to `admin.api.staging.example.com` and return these headers :

```
Set-Cookie: jwt=myToken; Domain=.staging.example.com; SameSite=None; Secure
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: 'Accept, Content-Type'
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: 'https://authenticate.staging.example.com'
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: 'GET,POST,PATCH,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS'
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: 'true'
```

3. When the user goes to `admin.staging.example.com` **or** `docs.staging.example.com`, the JWT cookie is sent for **all** the requests (index.html, etc.)

For now, I receive the cookie but it is not sent when I go to `admin.staging.example.com` or `docs.staging.example.com`. It is not a problem if the solution only works in latest Chrome.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've make it worked by adding `Path=/` and `HttpOnly` to my cookie